# How to model dependent categories (parent-child-relation)?

Tags: database-design, mariadb, query, table, mariadb-10.4

### Idea / Goal

I have two tables: `Article` (represents a Product) and `Category`. The relation is like this: An `Article` can be assigned to only one `Category` but a `Category` may have at least one `Article`s, therefore, `1:n (n >= 1)`.

Now, I want to build a category tree that holds up to 5 dependent `Category` entries. The category-hierarchy is constant. I have given each `Category` a `level` field that tells me how deep I am in the tree (1-5, 1 being the main category, 5 being the last leaf possible). Now I still need to know how to navigate ... I thought that I could just set a `parent_category` field that points to the upper category. The main categories, however, do not have a `parent_category` respectively they are set to `null`.

With this approach, I could query the databases for each level. This would make sense since I want to navigate through my categories and then see the sub-categories on entering a category (imagine a URL like: `%host%/category/sub-category`).

### Example

Please note: The data represented here is arbitrary. But the structure would be identical to this example below (I have omitted some other fields because they don't matter for this question):

**Article**

```
| id | name            | fk_category |
| -- | --------------- | ----------- |
| 1  | Apple           | 4           |
| 2  | Orange juice    | 3           |
```

**Category**

```
| id | name     | level | parent |
| -- | -------- | ----- | ------ |
| 1  | Fruits   | 1     | null   |
| 2  | Domestic | 2     | 1      |
| 3  | Juice    | 3     | 2      |
| 4  | Whatever | 3     | 2      |
```

The URL `%host%/fruits/domestic` would be resolved into a SQL-Query (simplified here) like:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM Category
WHERE level = 3
```

And then give me the names: "Juice" and "Whatever".

The URL `%host%/fruits/domestic/whatever` would be resolved into a SQL-Query (simplified here) like:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM Article
WHERE fk_category = 4
```

This should give me "Apple" (... and any other Articles that are within that category).

I am not sure yet how I should implement it that the Category also knows if it is a node without children. I could set a `boolean` for `has_children`.

### Question

How would you model this relationship? Is it okay to model it the way I had in mind? Is there a better alternative? Does it violate any rules?

Comment: Have a look at my answer to a functionally equivalent question on Stack Overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420885/how-do-i-design-a-database-to-store-properties-selecting-attributes-by-synonyms/7423459#7423459

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to separate the nodes subordination from the nodes itself. You need a pivot table `trees` having exactly two columns: `nodeID -- parentID`. The node having `parentID` equal to NULL is a root node for certain tree. Pivot table `trees` can contain more than one tree in it. This table requires a primary key (nodeID) and an unique multicolumn key (nodeID, parentID) - each node should be listed once and each node can have only one parent. An additional restriction - node can not refer to itself as a parent.

```
CREATE TABLE trees (
  nodeID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  parentID INT UNSIGNED, -- nullable for root nodes
  PRIMARY KEY ( nodeID ), -- each node is listed once
  UNIQUE KEY  ( nodeID, parentID ), -- no duplicates
  CONSTRAINT treeselfref CHECK ( nodeID <> parentID ) -- can't be parent for itself
)
```

Then you need a set of procedures for nodes manipulations:

```
AddNode( nodeID, parentID )
DeleteNode( nodeID ) -- you have to manage orphan childs
DeleteBranch( nodeID ) -- and all its childs/subchilds
GetParent( nodeID )  -- for the given node
GetChilds( parentID ) -- whos parent is parentID
GetBranch( parentID ) -- childs and their childs up to the leaves, ranked
GetLeaves( nodeID ) -- all leaves attached to the node
GetPath( nodeID ) -- full subordination path from the root up to the node, ranked
MergeBranches( nodeIDa, nodeIDb )
MoveBranch( nodeID, newParentID )
. . . . .
```

An exact set of procedures and their logic depend on the items/categories nature. So here is the sample code for the `GetLeaves( nodeID )` procedure, just for illustration of the basic principle:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (nodeID, parentID) AS 
( SELECT w.*   
    FROM trees AS w 
   WHERE w.nodeID = _nodeID  -- seed node for branch 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT q.*
    FROM cte   AS z
    JOIN trees AS q ON q.parentID = z.nodeID  -- childs, recurrent
) SELECT s.nodeID
    FROM cte        AS s
    LEFT JOIN trees AS r ON r.parentID = s.nodeID
  WHERE r.nodeID IS NULL; -- nodes not listed as parents for other nodes i.e. leaves
```

Here is the code for `GetPath( nodeID )` procedure that returns a list of all parent nodes from the tree root up to the given node, with rank (distance):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (rank, nodeID, parentID) AS 
( SELECT 0 AS rank, w.*
    FROM trees AS w 
   WHERE w.nodeID = _nodeID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT z.rank+1, q.*
    FROM cte   AS z
    JOIN trees AS q  ON q.nodeID = z.parentID
) SELECT s.*, f.name 
    FROM cte        AS s
    JOIN nodes      AS n ON n.ID = s.nodeID
    JOIN categories AS f ON f.ID = n.categoryID
   ORDER BY s.rank DESC
```

When invoked for nodeID = 123 it will return something like that:

```
+----+------+--------+----------+
|rank|nodeID|parentID|name      |
+----+------+--------+----------+
|  5 | 1    | NULL   | root     |
|  4 | 7    | 1      | edible   |
|  3 | 11   | 7      | fruit    |
|  2 | 31   | 11     | domestic |
|  1 | 42   | 31     | apple    |
|  0 | 123  | 42     | mcintosh |
+----+------+--------+----------+
```